# HttpResponse & Timeout for Android

Tags: java, android, timeout, httpresponse

I want my device to give up the http connexion after 5 seconds.
But my code does not work... I never get any timeout message when shutting network down.
Just like if the device still tries to connect, despite de timeout...

Have an idea?
Am I trying to catch the right exception?

Thanks.

```
        try 
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();       
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400) 
                {
                        ... //data processing
                } 
                else 
                {
                    errorMsgId = R.string.http_site_error;                        
                }
        } 
        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network timeout reached!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("+++++++++++++++++ ","Network timeout reached!"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

ok, GOT IT, so in case this could help someone else:

```
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    final HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
/**
 * Check availability of web service
 * 
 * @param host Address of host
 * @param seconds Timeout in seconds
 * @return Availability of host
 */
public static boolean checkIfURLExists(String host, int seconds)
{
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn;
    try
    {
        httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(host).openConnection();

        // Set timeouts in milliseconds
        httpUrlConn.setConnectTimeout(seconds * 1000);
        httpUrlConn.setReadTimeout(seconds * 1000);

        // Print HTTP status code/message for your information.
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + httpUrlConn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Response Message: "
                + httpUrlConn.getResponseMessage());

        return (httpUrlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: great yep... but if possible i would better include a timeout within my HttpResponse connexion order instead of making a connexion twice, because i am pretty sure my boss will notice it and won't like it :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but where are you associating the parameters that you set the timeout in with the `HttpClient` that you have created?  Shouldn't you do something like this:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
...
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

Comment: that's was also what i was thinking about as I found those exemples, but it seems to be that way...